# Excel VBA - Data From One Workbook to Another

Tags: excel, vba

I'm probably missing something simple here.  It just isn't copying the data from the source workbook to the target workbook and no errors are tripping.  The source workbook is opening just fine.  The target workbook contains this code. Both workbooks contain a sheet called 'Data'.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Sub TransferData()

   Dim wbTarget As Workbook
   Dim wbSource As Workbook

   Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open("C:\folder\source.xls")
   Set wbTarget = Workbooks.Open("C:\folder\target.xlsm")

   wbSource.Activate
   Sheets("Data").Select
   ActiveSheet.Range("B7").Copy

   wbTarget.Activate
   Sheets("Data").Select
   ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Paste

End Sub
```

Comment: Sheets("Data").Range("A1").Select
   ActiveSheet.Paste

Comment: @Fabrizio Did you mean Copy instead of Select?

Comment: See my edit - you need to specify which workbook you're copying from. `Sheets("Data").Select` is ambiguous because you have two workbooks with the sheet data open. Add `wbSource` and `wbTarget` as shown in my answer.

Comment: @Mark ?!?!??    wbTarget.Activate; 
   Sheets("Data").Range("A1").Select;
   ActiveSheet.Paste; now the code run correctly, whatever the best solution is to user1274820

Comment: @Fabrizio Nevermind. I thought you were trying to replace the whole chunk with one line (no activates or selects) which is a much better option. Didn't realize you were just modifying the last two lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is here:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("B7").Copy
```

Excel doesn't know which workbook to copy from:

```
With wbSource
    .Activate
    .Sheets("Data").Select
    .ActiveSheet.Range("B7").Copy
End With

With wbTarget
    .Activate
    .Sheets("Data").Select
    .ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Paste
End With
```

Try this code without select statements.

Also, you said the code is in your target workbook?

If you're opening both workbooks, the code should be in a third, unrelated workbook.

```
Sub TransferData()

   Dim wbTarget As Workbook
   Dim wbSource As Workbook

   Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open("C:\folder\source.xls")
   Set wbTarget = Workbooks.Open("C:\folder\target.xlsm")

   wbSource.Sheets("Data").Range("B7").Copy wbTarget.Sheets("Data").Range("A1")

   wbTarget.Close(True)
   wbSource.Close(True)

End Sub
```

Here is code I use on a daily basis to copy a spreadsheet from one workbook to another:

```
Dim TWB As Workbook
Dim CopyWB As Workbook
Set TWB = ThisWorkbook
Set CopyWB = Workbooks.Open(FName, ReadOnly:=True)
CopyWB.Sheets(TWB.Sheets("Menu").ComboBox1.Text).Cells.Copy TWB.Sheets("DataSheet").Cells
CopyWB.Close (False)
```

Comment: Thank you, User1274820!  Perfect!

Answer (score 0):

Can't you store the value instead of copy paste

```
Sub TransferData()
       Dim wbTarget As Workbook
       Dim wbSource As Workbook

       Set wbTarget = Application.ActiveWorkbook
       Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open("C:\folder\source.xls")


       wbSource.Activate
       Sheets("Data").Select
       xValue = ActiveSheet.Range("B7").Value

       wbTarget.Activate
       Sheets("Data").Select
       ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value = xValue
End Sub
```

Comment: Just tried this to no avail.  Basically acting the same way.

Comment: This should be equivalent to the simpler `wbTarget.Sheets("Data").Range("A1").Value = wbSource.Sheets("Data").Range("B7").Value`.